# ListView inside Column causes 'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height'

Tags: android, listview, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I am new to flutter and having trouble with layouts.

I want something like this:
[image: a sticky header and a scroll view below]

A sticky header and a scroll view below it.
I thought of using Column widget with two children - first being the header and second being the ListView.

Here is my code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Material(
   elevation: 8.0,
   child: Column(
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
     children: <Widget>[
       Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
         child: Text(
           title,
           style:
               Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead.copyWith(fontSize: 18.0),
           textAlign: TextAlign.left,
         ),
       ),
       Divider(height: 4.0),
       ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, i) {
         return ListTile(
           title: Text("Title $i"),
           subtitle: Text("Subtitle $i"),
         );
       }),
     ],
   ),
 );
}
```

I am getting the following error for it.

```
I/flutter ( 5725): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5725): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter ( 5725): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter ( 5725): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical
I/flutter ( 5725): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter ( 5725): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
I/flutter ( 5725): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
I/flutter ( 5725): there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
I/flutter ( 5725): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
I/flutter ( 5725): the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
```

I added made shrinkWrap of ListView true as mentioned in the message, but that didn't work either.

The parent of this layout is a stack containing various such layout-pages, all of this layout pages being offstage expect the one user has selected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also see https://medium.com/cwi-software/flutter-tips-and-tricks-1f0c0189185b#b23a

Comment: I think the title to this question could be improved.  Perhaps something like "ListView inside Column causes 'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height'" or "Vertical viewport was given unbounded height error with ListView"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try wrapping your `ListView.builder` with a `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget:

```
Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("Title $i"),
                  subtitle: Text("Subtitle $i"),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I don't know why Flexible is not mentioned in flutter documentation of [How to build layouts](https://flutter.io/tutorials/layout/). I've tried ConstrainedBox, FittedBox, Expand, etc everything... Thanks again for the help anyways.

Comment: this is related to your listview having unlimited number of children, it needs to be told how to fit into this unlimited size it was given

Comment: It does not work, now I am getting "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
"