# ListView inside Column throws error 'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height'

Tags: flutter, layout, dart

My question seems to be a duplicate of [ListView inside Column causes 'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681763/listview-inside-column-causes-vertical-viewport-was-given-unbounded-height) but the solution to add an `Expanded` or `Flexible` widget around the `ListView` doesn't work at all. It still throws the same error: `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.`

```
var data = ['a','b','c','d'];

Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(data[i], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24 * Rat.rat, color: Colors.white)),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
  ],
);
```

Obviously it can easily be fixed by adding a container around the `ListView` with a fixed height but there should be no need for that, I want it to be dynamically sized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Try something like this:

```
    class Esempio1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("WAKAWAKA"),
      ),
          body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("eg1"),
            Text("eg2"),
            Text("eg3"),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (ctx,i){
                  return ListTile(title: Text("aaaaaa$i"),);
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I just tried this code and it should do what you want.

The OP actually had the block of code posted contained inside another `Column`, that's why the `Expanded` wasn't working as it should when wrapped around the `ListView`. Wrapping the `Column` inside another `Expanded` solved the problem and made it all work as expected.

Comment: That gets rid of the error but also seems to disable scrolling on the listview. Now I get overflow warnings on a listview?? Kind of defeats the object of having a listview.

Comment: What are you triyng to achieve? Column are a non-scrollable widget so you cannot do that anyways. Why not just use your listview? otherwise, why not keep your listview like that and then wrap your column in a SingleChildScrollView?

Comment: The column has a few text widgets above the listview which differ in size each time and are fixed, with no need to scroll. The listview should take up the rest of the screen to the bottom and should be scrollable since it will differ in length each time.

Comment: Alright but I think this might be a bug. I can't see any reason why Expanded doesn't work here. It should allow the Listview to take up the rest of the screen and still scroll.

Comment: Any idea why shrinkwrap disables scrolling? Seems also like a bug since that doesn't seem to be the function of shrinkwrap.

Comment: I just updated the code. Take a look, try it in a different page maybe and tell me if there are other problems

Comment: Yeah that does work. Not sure what's different with that and my code, I'm looking into it.

Comment: Oh it didn't work in my code because the column is actually also in another column. Wrapping that column in an Expanded widget as well solves the problem.

Comment: Can I edit your question and explain this and then I can accept it as the best answer?

Comment: yeah sure! why not!

Comment: I meant edit your 'answer' of course, not question. Check my edit and see if it's ok or not.

Comment: That's perfect for me!

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot for your help. Sometimes seeing it all on a separate page reveals the problem clearly. So many refactored widgets everywhere I lost sight that it was a column inside a column. I'm glad it's not a bug although the shrinkwrap thing does still seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping ListView builder in SingleChildScrollView and setting up its physics to

```
 physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: Still throws the same error: `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.`

Comment: changing shrinkwrap to true might help

Comment: That doesn't work either since you can see in the answer below, shrinkwrap true disables scrolling on the listview. I think listview is pretty buggy to be honest.